# Can't connect to Samsung GT-B2710 via usb

Tags: samsung, phone, usb-drive

When I connect my phone with memory card in it with usb cable to my ubuntu notebook

```
DBus error org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor.NotFound: The given volume was not found
```

error message is shown and following is written to the syslog:

```
May 31 18:29:42 edbwp400322 kernel: [184240.427259] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
May 31 18:29:42 edbwp400322 kernel: [184240.524759] scsi10 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
May 31 18:29:42 edbwp400322 mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1"
May 31 18:29:42 edbwp400322 mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 6 was not an MTP device
May 31 18:29:43 edbwp400322 kernel: [184241.522802] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  GT-B2710-CARD    2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
May 31 18:29:43 edbwp400322 kernel: [184241.524147] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
May 31 18:29:43 edbwp400322 kernel: [184241.525184] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] 3911680 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 GB/1.86 GiB)
May 31 18:29:43 edbwp400322 kernel: [184241.526410] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
May 31 18:29:43 edbwp400322 kernel: [184241.526413] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 0f 0e 00 00
May 31 18:29:43 edbwp400322 kernel: [184241.527125] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
May 31 18:29:43 edbwp400322 kernel: [184241.536461]  sdb: sdb1
May 31 18:29:43 edbwp400322 kernel: [184241.541653] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
May 31 18:29:44 edbwp400322 usb_modeswitch: switching device 04e8:f000 on 002/006
May 31 18:29:44 edbwp400322 kernel: [184242.332659] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
```

Is there any chance to access phone's memory card as memory stick?

Best regards, Eugene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [**here**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-modeswitch/+bug/755342):

> This is a problem with the `usb-modeswitch`, if you disable it in `/etc/usb_modeswitch.conf` => `DisableSwitching=1` then it works.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Whilst the link may answer the question, it would be preferable to add details of the answer here in case the link expires/changes.